# Building JBPM in eclipse

Tags: jbpm, building

i am trying to build JBPM in Eclipse IDE.i am using eclipse Helios Service Release 2 and jdk1.5 in linux.i am using command `" [user@localhost jbpm4]$` maven clean install " in shell,but i got this error.

```
[user@localhost jbpm4]$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   jBPM 4
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Log
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - API
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Test Base
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - PVM
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - jPDL
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration SPI
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration JBoss 5
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration JBoss 4
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration Console
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration Form Plugin
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration GraphView Plugin
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Integration Reports
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Examples
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Test DB
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Test POJO
[INFO]   jBPM 4 - Migration - Tool
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jBPM 4
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/user/Nitin/Jbpm/jbpm4/pom.xml to /home/user/.m2/repository/org/jbpm/jbpm4/jbpm/4.0/jbpm-4.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jBPM 4 - Log
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/Nitin/Jbpm/jbpm4/modules/log/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /home/user/Nitin/Jbpm/jbpm4/modules/log/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
/home/user/Nitin/Jbpm/jbpm4/modules/log/src/main/java/org/jbpm/internal/log/LogFormatter.java:[14,7] error while writing org.jbpm.internal.log.LogFormatter: /home/user/Nitin/Jbpm/jbpm4/modules/log/target/classes/org/jbpm/internal/log/LogFormatter.class (No such file or directory)


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 21 12:18:41 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/26M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

plz help me how i build Jbpm by using eclipse ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trunk works for me in commandline:

> ```
> svn co http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbpm/jbpm4/trunk
> cd trunk/
> mvn clean install
> ```

which version are you using?